# Facebook js api for public photo returns unsupported get request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am trying to use facebook javascript api to get the details of a public photo uploaded by a user. The photo_id is 645046238933001, and i am using this code:
FB.api('/645046238933001', function(response){...} ). the code is executed in a browser when a user is logged in to my app using facebook.

Using graph api explorer and an app access token i am able to get the photo object but with any other valid user access token  (not the user uploaded the photo) facebook returns "unsupported get request..." (using graph api explorer)

what might be the problem?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

That´s intentional. Even if the photo is public, you still need a User Token of the correct user to get access with the API.

The [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/photo#read) are a bit misleading, the info seems to be outdated because it actually would only be possible for photos on Pages:

> Any valid access token for any photo with public privacy settings.

...in the next line there´s the correct info:

> For any photos uploaded by someone, and any photos in which they have
>   been tagged - A user access token for that person with user_photos
>   permission

Also, even if you would get the photo of another user: It is not possible to like a post/photo on Facebook with the API.

Comment: so other users can not view public objects? i am having problems with posting likes to this photo from other users. return error: 200 permissions error.. what is going on??

Comment: the graph api says: 'Any valid access token for any photo with public privacy settings.' at [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/photo)

Comment: not with the api, no. it would be way too easy to build scrapers - which is not allowed.

Comment: why would you like the photo with the api anyway? users can just use facebook to do that. anyway, i believe the docs are outdated.

Comment: what about posting likes? is this now allowed also?

Comment: depends how you are trying to do it. if it´s without user authorization, it´s not allowed of course. and i don´t mean login, i mean every single like or action has to get approved before it´s done. btw, i edited my question with some more information.

Comment: user trying to post like has granted publish_actions to my app.. is this not enough?

Comment: no, that´s not enough. you still have to let the user approve every single action (like, comment, whatever). else you would not get publish_actions approved anyway. autoliking or autoposting is spam. not cool ;)

Comment: could you please point me to some examples? How would i let the user approve a single post?

Comment: for example, by presenting a button that says "like this photo on facebook".

Comment: that is what i am doing. I have alink, say with id fblike, and with jquery:

Comment: ok, should be good enough then. but still, you need a user token for the user who uploaded the photo to get access. meaning, you cannot like a photo someone else uploaded - only a photo of a facebook page.

Comment: thank you very much, you are very kind. i am sorry i cannot vote up for your answer. Not enough reputation.

Comment: sorry, it seems it's not my day.